# How can I create a new Spinner dynamically after itemSelected?

Tags: android

I have a Spinner element in one Android Activity.

Now I want that, if I selected on Item of this Spinner, I should be able to create a new Spinner and put it into in my activity. If I select one Item of this second Spinner, I should be able to create a new Spinner ....

so this is the code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_insert_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);
        builder.setTitle("Insert Alerts");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        listValueSet_Agent = new ArrayList<AlertValueSet>();
        valueSet = new AlertValueSet("2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","106190000",
                "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Penicillin","SNOMED CT");
        listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
        valueSet = new AlertValueSet("2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","281647001",
                "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Aspirin","SNOMED CT");
        listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
        valueSet = new AlertValueSet("2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","282100009",
                "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Codeine","SNOMED CT");
        listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
        valueSet = new AlertValueSet("2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","282100009",
                "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Select Agent","SNOMED CT");
        listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);

        //spinner status
        Spinner sAgent = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.combo_agent);
        adapterAgent = new ArrayAdapter<AlertValueSet>(v.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listValueSet_Agent);
        sAgent.setAdapter(adapterAgent);
        sAgent.setSelection(0);
        sAgent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
        return builder.create();
}
```

This class is instead, the implementation of OnItemSelectedListener class:

```
public class SpinnerActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

            Spinner spinnerAgentN = new Spinner(v.getContext());
            spinnerAgentN.setAdapter(adapterAgent);
            spinnerAgentN.setSelection(listValueSet_Agent.size()-1);
            spinnerAgentN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layoutText);
            linearLayout.addView(spinnerAgentN,2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    }
```

Now the problem is, if I try to run my application, this method (onItemSelected) is called for every time, and I can see in my activity N spinner, but this is not good.

If I try to delete this code:

```
spinnerAgentN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
```

I don't have any problem.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: I think rather then creating new spinner every time, you should change the adapter data based on the selected item.

Comment: Can you explain me, your solution?

Answer (score 0):

while data is set to the adapter, then called onitem click listener automatically. So in on item click listener method you have to check the position value. if the position value is 0 then you don't have set the data to second spinner otherwise you have to set the data to second spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Inside onItemSelected()

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        AlertValueSet set = listValueSet_Agent.get(pos);
        // Fetch new data based on the selected item and set it back to the spinner

        adapterAgent = new ArrayAdapter<AlertValueSet>(v.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listValueSet_Agent);
        sAgent.setAdapter(adapterAgent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of code and requirement, there are two options for resolve your query.

**But I will explain only one which is fit for your requirement**

just declare your array as below.

```
   listValueSet_Agent = new ArrayList<AlertValueSet>();
    valueSet = new AlertValueSet("Select","2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","106190000",
            "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Penicillin","SNOMED CT");
    listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
    valueSet = new AlertValueSet("Select","2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","281647001",
            "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Aspirin","SNOMED CT");
    listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
    valueSet = new AlertValueSet("Select","2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","282100009",
            "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Codeine","SNOMED CT");
    listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
    valueSet = new AlertValueSet("Select","2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4","282100009",
            "2.16.840.1.113883.6.96","Select Agent","SNOMED CT");
    listValueSet_Agent.add(valueSet);
```

Now, change your onItemSelected method as below,

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

        if(pos > 0)
        {
            Spinner spinnerAgentN = new Spinner(v.getContext());
            spinnerAgentN.setAdapter(adapterAgent);
            spinnerAgentN.setSelection(listValueSet_Agent.size()-1);
            spinnerAgentN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layoutText);
            linearLayout.addView(spinnerAgentN,2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
```